# GATE $2018$ - Probability question : The probability that one of them wins on the third trial is ____ .

Tags: probability, binomial-theorem, dice, binomial-distribution

> Two people, $P$ and $Q$, decide to independently roll two identical dice, each with $6$ faces, numbered $1$ to $6$. The person with the lower number wins, In case of a tie, the roll the dice repeatedly until there is no tie. Define a trial as a throw of the dice by $P$ and $Q$. Assume that all $6$ numbers on each dice are equi-probable and that all trials are independent. The probability (rounded to 3 decimal places) that one of them wins on the third trial is ________ .

---

#### My Try:

A person with lower number wins, so sample space is $\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}$ and chances $= 5/6$.

The probability that one of them wins in 3rd trial

$=$ lost in first trial * lost in first trial * wins in the third trial

$= 1/6 *1/6*5/6 = 5/216 =0.023$

> Could you please solve it?

Thanks in advance.

---

#### Edit1:

This examination was held yesterday, I posted this based on memory.

#### Edit2:

They published it. I edited the question, this is original question:
[image]

Comment: ...in case of a tie between them... ?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, do you like suppressing voice, you deleted my and Fawad's comment. These comments were showing mirror for blind down-votes and close votes. If you like such, delete my ID too :(

Comment: FYI Fawad managed to delete their comment themself. And, comments complaining about unexplained downvotes are generally deemed useless. Do you ever read meta?

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Some weaknesses remain. For example, you probably meant to write "a tie in a first trial, a tie in the 2nd, and a non-tie in the 3rd" or some variant there of. I would think that here "win/loss" is from the point of view of particular player. So in any given round the probabilities for Win/Tie/Loss are $P(W)=5/12$, $P(T)=1/6$, $P(L)=5/12$ as you can confirm yourself by examining the sample space closely.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, I agreed with your explanation. It seems valid and required probability should be $=1/6*1/6*5/12$. I'll update this post when they publish this question paper. Thanks.

Comment: No. That product is the probability of player A winning on the third round. Your formula gives the correct probability for one of them (= either one of them) to win on the third round.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, http://gate.iitg.ac.in/ published Question Paper and Answer Keys yesterday. I am unable to login right-now due to technical error, so I will edit answer here later. Can we reopen this post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The probability that one of $P$ or $Q$ wins in the third trial is the probability that they draw (have equal dice) in the first two trials, and have different dice in the third trial.

A draw happens only when both dice show the same value.

\begin{align*}
\mathbf{P}[ \text{draw} ] & = \mathbf{P}[P = Q] \\
& = \sum_{i=1}^6 \mathbf{P}[P= Q = i] \\
& = \sum_{i=1}^6 \mathbf{P}[P=i] \mathbf{P}[Q = i] \\
& = \sum_{i=1}^6 \frac16 \times \frac16\\
& = \frac16.
\end{align*}

Since trials are independent

\begin{align*}
\mathbf{P}[ \text{win in round $3$}] & = \mathbf{P}[ \text{draw in round $1$}] \, \mathbf{P}[ \text{draw in round $2$}] \, \mathbf{P}[ \text{not a draw in round $3$}] \\
& = \frac16 \times \frac16 \times \frac56 \\
& = \frac5{216}
\end{align*}

Note that whilst our results are the same, I'm not sure based on your language (referring to loses) whether you have used the same logic. A loss suggests that one person lost, and the other won. In this calculation we must count draws: i.e. neither person won.

Comment: Thanks for nice explanation.